# ¿Cómo elimino la línea que contiene exactamente una cadena con barras?

Tags: sed

Quiero eliminar con Sed una línea de fichero con barras separadoras, por ejemplo tengo el siguiente 
fichero test.txt:

```
test1 = /var/hello
test2 = /var/hello
test3 = /var/hello
```

Y quiero eliminar el test2. Lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
sed -i '/test2 = \/var\hello/d' test.txt
```

Pero no me funciona.

He mirado en internet pero no encuentro ninguna explicación de cómo poder solucionarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No me queda muy claro lo que quieres hacer, pero si lo que quieres es borrar las líneas que empiecen por test2 (independientemente de lo que haya después) lo puedes hacer así:

```
sed -i '/^test2/d' test.txt
```

Si necesitas que se borre exactamente la línea con el texto que has puesto lo que tienes que hacer es escapar bien las barras:

```
sed -i '/test2 = \/var\/hello/d' test.txt
```

Te faltaba una barra delante de hello

Comment: joder, Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, @viache19? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza solo la primera palabra, ya que esta es distintiva para toda la linea:

```
 sed '/test2/d' test.txt
```

Sin embargo, el comando sed no modifica el archivo test.txt. Si lo quieres hacer tendrías que redireccionar la salida hacia otro archivo: No lo hagas sobre el mismo porque lo pierdes

```
sed '/test2/d' test.txt>test1.txt
```

test1.txt es el archivo con el resultado. Si lo quieres con el mismo nombre, entonces cópialo luego del sed:

```
sed '/test2/d' test.txt>test1.txt && mv test1.txt test.txt
```

Comment: OP ha usado el flag -i que es precisamente para modificar el fichero de entrada y no tener que hacer redirecciones.

Comment: ok. Yo generalmente no lo utilizo por precaución. A pesar del bak siempre que no te olvides del sufijo porque o sino fuiste.

Comment: @ordago nótese de todos modos que internamente `-i` está haciendo redirecciones. Yo también tiendo a redirigir porque con `-i` es fácil olvidarse de añadir extensión y con ello perder el fichero original.